# Application Error when i run my heroku app

Tags: java, heroku, ftp

I'm working with a java app which i have deployed in heroku. When i run the heroku app, the app should go to my host and read all the csv files. Every row in this file should be saved in a table row.

My problem is that: If my csv files are too big, when i run the app it resulted in an app error. Doing some test I sow that if the number of row was around 600 the app run with success,if there were more then 600 there was an app error.

Can somebody explain why this happens?

Comment: What error message do you get? Can you tell us more about the database, and frameworks you are using?

Comment: The error is : "Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments."

I'm using postgres sql, the heroku database.

Comment: What's the error in your Heroku logs (you can check by running `heroku logs --tail`)?

Comment: Are you loading this CSV file at startup of your `web` process? Heroku has a 60-second boot timeout (if your app doesn't start in 60-sec it's considered failed).

Comment: Thanks a lot. While my heroku web app give me an application error looking at the logs i sow that the execution was going on, and my data are inserted in my database.